# Why stars are named Gliese?

Tags: star, exoplanet, naming

There are exoplanets called Gliese 581c, Gliese 581d etc. I assume their star is [Gliese 581](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gliese_581). So where does this Gliese come from?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They come from Gliese's catalog of nearby stars (various editions and co-author), the number is the star's catalog number.